Make symbolic link as admin with New-Item and subprocess
I got PS working CmdLet:
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\Users\user1\Saved Games\Scripts\BIOS" -Target "C:\Users\user1\Saved Games\bios\Scripts\BIOS"

I need run as Admin (of course) so wrap around Start-Process and pass to Python's subprocess
I image it can be something like:
def run_cmd(*args):
    p = subprocess.Popen(*args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = p.communicate()
    return out, error

cmd_symlink = '"New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\Users\user1\Saved Games\Scripts\BIOS" -Target "C:\Users\user1\Saved Games\bios\Scripts\BIOS"'
ps_command = f"& {{Start-Process powershell.exe -argumentlist '-command {cmd_symlink}' -Verb RunAs}}"
command = ['powershell.exe', '-command', ps_command]
run_cmd(command)

or????
Solution:
cmd_symlink = r'"New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path \"C:\Users\user1\Saved Games\Scripts\BIOS\" -Target \"C:\Users\user1\Saved Games\bios\Scripts\BIOS\"'
ps_command = f"Start-Process pwsh.exe -argumentlist '-command {cmd_symlink}' -Verb RunAs"
command = ['pwsh.exe', '-command', ps_command]
run_cmd(command)


In short: " characters that are to be retained as part of PowerShell code passed to the PowerShell CLI's -Command parameter must be escaped as \". See the linked duplicate for details.

As an aside: There's no reason to use & { ... } in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the -Command (-c) parameter - just use ... directly. Older versions of the CLI documentation erroneously suggested that & { ... } is required, but this has since been corrected.

Therefore (note the raw string, r'...'):
cmd_symlink = r'"New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path \"C:\Users\user1\Saved Games\Scripts\BIOS\" -Target \"C:\Users\user1\Saved Games\bios\Scripts\BIOS\"'
and
ps_command = f"Start-Process powershell.exe -argumentlist '-command {cmd_symlink}' -Verb RunAs"

@mklement0 it is working. Worth mention for others that \"C:\Users\user1\Saved Games\Scripts\BIOS\" last \" is just escaped quote not backslash and quote. So If you need backslash at end of path you need \"C:\Users\user1\Saved Games\Scripts\BIOS\\\"
